# Uploaded an image got [Error 111] using Cloudinary on Pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, web-deployment, cloudinary, pythonanywhere

I'm using Pythonanywhere to store my Django code and everything run properly except when I'm trying to upload an image.

I got this error:

```
cloudinary.exceptions.Error: Unexpected error - MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.cloudinary.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1_1/MY-CLOUD-NAME/image/upload (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f5de5f6e6d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))")
```

This is my code in model.py:

```py
from cloudinary.models import CloudinaryField

some class
    project_image = CloudinaryField("project_img", proxy="http://proxy.server:3128")
```

This is my code in setting.py:

```py
CLOUDINARY = {
  'cloud_name': 'CLOUD-NAME',  
  'api_key': 'xx',  
  'api_secret': 'xx,
}

CLOUDINARY_URL='cloudinary://xxx@CLOUD-NAME?api_proxy=proxy.server:3128'
```

I also tried to change the proxy.server part to:

```py
- https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/MY-CLOUD-NAME
```

and add the api_proxy in `CLOUDINARY`  parameter but It didn't work also

P.S. I'm using a free Pythonanywhere account and I do some research and the owner said that I have to set the proxy to `proxy.server:3128` but I don't know how to do that

P.S.2 What I've tried to do so far

- upgrade urllib but didn't work out
- try to add a proxy in many different ways on setting.py as you saw above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your settings try setting the api as follows:

```
CLOUDINARY = {
  'cloud_name': 'CLOUD-NAME',  
  'api_key': 'xx',  
  'api_secret': 'xx',
  'api_proxy': 'http://proxy.server:3128'
}
```

As referred in [this](https://github.com/cloudinary/pycloudinary/issues/183#issuecomment-550293397) github issue comment.

Comment: I've just tried this but it throws me another error ``` Error code: Unhandled Exception``` on the main site and another long error on the log page``` Error running WSGI application, urllib3.exceptions.ProxySchemeUnknown: Not supported proxy scheme None```

Comment: I have added the protocol to the proxy url does that work?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a pythonanywhere free account, then it is not letting you access the CDN URL because it is not whitelisted. You must upgrade to a paid account in order for your app to be able to access this URL.